# How to upgrade to the latest version from my current Ubuntu version 11.10 without data loss

Tags: upgrade

How can I upgrade to the latest Ubuntu version from the present version 11.10 on my DELL Inspiron N5050 laptop without data loss.
Also inform how can download the latest version.